# How to create a smallest hash with less character in a url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following Hash.EncodeMD5(p) that take a value p and Encode it, and eventually it get passed into a url as such:

www.mysite/test/test.aspx?perm=?|1098951-c2bcc0d267304a3d7d663007dbf801bc|1011796-3af44ad8442000232390799c367a06ed|

My problem is my url can be very long in length. and how can I reduce it's length? I believe the issue is Hash.EncodeMD5(p);

```
        string[] x = (Request.Form["ID"]).Split(',');

        foreach (string pp in x)
        {
            perm += pp + "-" + Hash.EncodeMD5(pp);
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you add both the original parameter and its hash to the query string?

Comment: Define "very long"

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these without shortening the hash :

1. Store the very long hash value in a cookie that you read later server-side.
2. Hide the values in some hidden Asp.Net/HTML controls.
3. Hide the values (client-side) via `window.localStorage`. This solution might not work but it worths the try.